# Same set of instructions, different types. How to handle?

Tags: c, generic-programming

In a C program I'm making, I will receive as command lines arguments a file path and a letter. The file is where I read data from, and the letter represents the type of data that is held inside that file.

The instructions I need to perform on the data are basically the same, only the type is different: it might be that the file holds `int`s, `double`s or the values of a struct `X`. Regardless of type, the operations will be identical; how can I avoid repeating code? In C++ I would handle this with templates. How would this be typically handled in C?

Comment: Is the code _exactly_ the same (i.e. `s/int/double/g` and it works)?

Comment: Using void pointers and macros with type arguments?

Comment: @Mat Exactly the same, except the underlying type and some custom sorting criteria for each type. It doesn't work yet because I haven't written it.

Answer (score 0):

In C you would do it through what you're hoping to avoid -- repeating the code. C++ makes this more convenient with templates, as you're aware, however that's just a simple way to repeat the code and base it on a different type.

Something that might be appropriate for you is to provide the different class functions but to not call them directly. Instead, based on your command line, determine once which function(s) will process your data, and assign them to function pointers. Then, your control loop will just generically call the processing function(s) using those pointer(s). This will obviously include whatever you do with the data, but you might also decide to have separate input functions based on data type.

Edit: As Mat says, there are come types which promote well and so one block of code would work fine. I suspect this is why your assignment includes working with some structure type.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is obvious with modern objected oriented languages -- you make an object of each type that implements an interface (or via inheritance) of the actions you want to perform.

You can't do this in C because the language does not naively support object oriented, but you can "reproduce" the same functionality instead of letting the compiler do it for you.  To do so you need to use a level of indirection specifically you will need to use function pointers.

So (as an example) one of the actions you might take is to read values from the file.  One of your variables will be a function pointer to a function that takes as a parameter the file and a variable of type void (this will change for each function you write.)  Write the function for each of your types and then at run type assign the function to use based on the type of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the realms of really ugly pre-processor tricks, if you want to replicate the body of a function for different types, but keep the code "structure" identical, you can do something like this:

#### foo.hc

```
#define YNAME(X) foo_ ## X
#define XNAME(X) YNAME(X)
#define NAME XNAME(TYPE)

int NAME(FILE* f) {
    TYPE myvar;
    ...
    return whatever;
}
```

#### foo.c

```
#define TYPE int
#include "foo.hc"
#undef TYPE

#define TYPE double
#include "foo.hc"
#undef TYPE
```

This `foo.c` will pre-process to:

```
int foo_int(FILE* f) {
    int myvar;
    ...
    return whatever;
}

int foo_double(FILE* f) {
    double myvar;
    ...
    return whatever;
}
```

All you need to do in your main processing loop with that is to dispatch to the right function depending on your file type. A plain switch statement can work pretty well, an array of function pointers could work too.

Answer (score 0):

The new C standard, C11, has type generic expressions that you could use for this. There is not yet much compiler support for C11 but for example the latest version of clang has `_Generic`. You can also use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__C11.html) to emulate C11 features on top of similar extensions that are provided by gcc.